# Cannot create com object - Powershell

Tags: powershell-4.0, sccm

Below is the msg while creating a New-Object (Powershell)

I tried opening Powershell

1. as Admin
2. 32bit ISE
3. 64bit ISE

Nothing helped

```
> New-Object : Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
> {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} failed due to the  following
> error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT:
> 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)). At line:1 char:8
> + $obj = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.SMS.Client -Strict
> +        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [New-Object], COMException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoCOMClassIdentified,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

Comment: What command are you running?

Comment: $obj = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.SMS.Client -Strict

Comment: Probably a stupid question but you do this on a machine with installed sccm client right?

Comment: I was able find alternative way to set the site code and fix the issue. but still not sure what is wrong with this method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able find alternative way to set the site code which I was trying to earlier with the com-object and fix the issue. but still not sure what is wrong with the above method